# Export one field from access to specific cell in excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I want to place a name from a table/query to a specific cell from access. I have a check sheet with lots of data in other cells that at the top has the persons name at the top. I would like a button that can be clicked that will open THAT file and insert the desired name into it via VBA. I'm aware on how to do this with VBA to a word doc with bookmarks, but now sure how to define the 'bookmark' for a cell in excel.

This is what I have so far.

```
Private Sub Cmdopentarget1_Click()
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim wbTarget1 As Workbook
Dim qdfquerytest As QueryDef
Dim rsquerytest As Recordset
Set qdfquerytest = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("query1")
Set qdfsecondquery = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("query2")
Set rsquerytest = qdfquerytest.OpenRecordset()
Set rssecondquery = qdfsecondquery.OpenRecordset()
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
xl.Visible = True
Set wbTarget1 = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Owner\Dropbox\Target1.xlsx")
'Set wbTarget1 = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Dennis\Dropbox\Target1.xlsx")
'wbTarget1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(8, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsquerytest
wbTarget1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rsquerytest
wbTarget1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5").CopyFromRecordset rssecondquery
```

It works, but the query I have returns TWO fields, Fullname and the position, I need to only have the FullName in the excel cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
[variable or object] = rsquerytest(0).Value
```

to pull the value from a record. The recordset starts at position 0. If you wanted the second column, you would use `rsquerytest(1).Value`.

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834457.aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure where to place that.  Would that be in the Range line? The data I need would be in the 0 value, the 1 value is the position field, not needed.

Comment: `...Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = rsquerytest(0).Value` should set cell `A1` to the returned `Fullname`.

Comment: That worked, but everyother time, I get the debug error with a blank excel sheet.  I'm sure it's my error handling or overall syntax.  I've seen so many different methods of doing this.